# Imrpove Barcode Image Quality PNG

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, zxing

I am currently using ZXing.Net to generate a CODE_128 (which in the documentation says is compliant with GS1-128 barcodes). The code I am using is down below:

```
BarcodeWriterPixelData writer = new BarcodeWriterPixelData()
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Width = 280,
        Height = 80
    }
};
var pixelData = writer.Write(packageModel.TrackingId.PrintValue);

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pixelData.Width, pixelData.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        try
        {
            // we assume that the row stride of the bitmap is aligned to 4 byte multiplied by the width of the image   
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelData.Pixels, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, pixelData.Pixels.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }

        // PNG or JPEG or whatever you want
        bitmap.SetResolution(100F, 100F);
        drawing.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(10, 255, 280, 80));
    }
}
```

This creates the image below

[image: Barcode Generated by Code]

For some reason my barcode is coming out blurry and with grey shadows on it. I am even setting the barcode resolution to be 100DPI x 100DPI to make it printer friendly.

My question:
What can I add to my code to make the barcode look crisp and blur free?

Comment: 100 dpi isn't that much when you print it on paper. Monitors etc. have 75-90-ish DPI (i.e. 1680x1050 pixel and 22" monitor = 90 dpi). For Print, 200-300 dpi is suitable

Comment: @Tseng i will try that thank you for the advice.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if possible, you should change to QR-code. I have used both on printed reports and QR-code's are much better to scan.